# Google Sheets: Automatically add date formula to last row

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm posting information from a form to google sheets.

After the insert (which adds the last row), I want to do some apps script post processing.  Before I do the post processing I want to fill in a couple of blank cells which are not submitted by the form, including the OFFEREXPIRATIONDATE column which should be set at :

```
=TODAY()+7
```

I've been reading https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/array-formulas-forms/ , but I'm not sure if you can apply Arrayformulas to add new formulas into cells.

I tried putting the following in cell J2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"TODAY + 7";J3:INDEX(J:J,IF(ISBLANK(I3),"",TODAY()+7))})
```

with the idea of checking if the row to the left is blank, and if not inserting the TODAY()+7 formula in, but this is giving a circular dependancy error.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Bind a form submit trigger to write the formula in r1c1 format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting one of these two in J2 should do the trick:

Insert date in J unless I is empty:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(to_date(if(I2:I="","",today()+7)))
```

Insert date in J unless I is #VALUE! or empty (in case you don't want to insert a date either when cells in I get an error):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(to_date(IFERROR(if(I2:I="","",today()+7),"")))
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with the second option. Do you mind explaining a little more about what you are doing here. - its kind of a complex formula for a beginner.

Comment: Sure. From the inside to the outside: first you check if the cells in the I column are empty, if they are, don't do anything, if they are not then today()+7. IFERROR checks if the cell has an error (e.g. #VALUE!, #N/A...), the first parameter is what to do if the value is not an error, the second if it is then don't do anything. IFERROR(value, [value_if_error]). Finally to_date converts the format that you would regularly get e.g. 43444 for 10/12/2018 and converts it to 10/12/2018. Arrayformula is explained properly in the Ben Collins link you wrote.

Comment: You can always read more about these functions here (with examples and so on):
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239

Comment: do you mind looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599579/sheets-to-date-formula-to-get-date-from-timestamp ?